# python.exe output

Tags: redirect, syntax-error, python

I've got an application that uses python as a script language. When somebody modifies a python script i want to known if it has syntax errors. I am using the python.exe (windows 2003, python 2.5) to check the script so i execute something like

```
python script.py > errors.txt
```

but errors.txt remains 0kb despite script.py has syntax errors, in that case, the errors detected by python are showed in the screen (but not redirected to the file)

Comment: python -ud script.py > errors.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If python uses the STDERR output stream for errors (I admit I do not know if it does), you must insted redirect the error strem by using:

```
python script.py 2> errors.txt
```

Comment: Yes... That it's... I was writting my own answer with that but you post it first. Thanks